# A generic editor for trees and graphs of text

Tags: database, file-management, text-editor, editor, data-structure

I am missing a generic editor, similar to a plain text code editor (like Kate), but not for lines of text, but for trees and graphs of lines of text or variant data records.

I always wondered why this is not a standard tool in every operating system.

I just want to be able to
• navigate the tree/graph like a directory tree or list, with the cursor (up/down) plus some way to enter/escape the levels. And
• re-order, insert and remove the elements with ease, just like I would in a plan text editor or file manager. (E.g. select five lines, skip one, select another three, and move them to another node (compare: directory, project, etc).
• But also edit the lines without anything special (either directly, or by pressing a key, like e.g. F2 in spreadsheet software).
• And finally, it is important, to be able to sort and filter the tree/graph, both directly, and merely as a “view” (as it would be called in a database). The closer it comes to the abilities of SQL SELECT, without becoming actual programming, the better.

Of course it must open and save some very standardized simple file format, that can be opened in other editors (whichever that may be), not only to allow scripting it.

So like fusing a plain text editor, a XML editor, an SQL table editor, and a file manager.
(Without the mouse clicking, and without requiring features specific to only one of those.)

Big pluses would be:
• A graph (network of nodes and edges with loops in them) feature. If available, can be implemented by references (similar to softlinks, pointers). Allowing me to give graph edges a type would be awesome. (Say to distinguish groupings from dependencies.)
• Allowing for fields/columns instead of text lines.
• Actively being scripting-friendly.
• And the ability to handle basic markup/markdown formats or other compatible file formats (if there are any).

The less closed-sourcey, non-free, desktopy, mousey, minimalisty, mobiley, appley, weby or cloudy the program is, the better. Text mode is fine too. Ugly-looking is fine. Ancient or even abandoned software is just as fine.
***It needs to get the job done, first and foremost.***

I intend to run it on Linux (terminal, KDE, just plain X) and in Termux (without or with proot) or plain Android.

I’m sure almost everyone could use a tool like that, if it’s truly universal.
But is there even anything like this? Anything that comes even close?